# Customize the "edit" link in bookdown

Tags: r, blogdown, gitbook

I use bookdown with the gitbook ouput to build a book. The `.Rmd` files used to build this book are in turn auto-generated from other source files in the following workflow: An R-Script takes `folder1/file.txt` and generates the file `folder2/file.Rmd`, which is in turn used to build the book.

So far, so good. However, when I use [the `edit` option](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html) in `_bookdown.yaml` the link (naturally) refers to `folder2/file.Rmd`. It would be a simple thing to replace `folder2` with `folder1` and `.Rmd` with `.txt`, but I don't know where I should start.

In [R/html.R](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/R/html.R) (in the bookdown package), the link is generated within the function `build_chapter` using `rmd_cur` as input (which is "*The Rmd filename of the current chapter*") and the function `source_link`.

```
source_link = function(target, type) {
  if (length(target) == 0) return()
  setting = source_link_setting(type = type)
  if (is.null(setting)) return()
  button_link(sprintf(setting$link, target), setting$text)
}
```

How can I use this information to generate my custom link that points to `folder1/file.txt` instead of `folder2/file.Rmd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the history and view to also link to the text file

```r
source_link = function(target, type) {
  if (length(target) == 0) return()
  setting = source_link_setting(type = type)
  if (is.null(setting)) return()
  button_link(sprintf(setting$link, sub("folder2/(.+?)\\.[Rr]md$", "folder1/\\1.txt", target)), setting$text)
}
```

otherwise overload the `build_chapter` function:

```r
build_chapter = function(
  head, toc, chapter, link_prev, link_next, rmd_cur, html_cur, foot
) {
  # add a has-sub class to the <li> items that has sub lists
  toc = gsub('^(<li>)(.+<ul>)$', '<li class="has-sub">\\2', toc)
  paste(c(
    head,
    '<div class="row">',
    '<div class="col-sm-12">',
    toc,
    '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="row">',
    '<div class="col-sm-12">',
    chapter,
    '<p style="text-align: center;">',
    button_link(link_prev, 'Previous'),
    source_link(sub("folder2/(.+?)\\.[Rr]md$", "folder1/\\1.txt", rmd_cur), type = 'edit'),
    source_link(rmd_cur, type = 'history'),
    source_link(rmd_cur, type = 'view'),
    button_link(link_next, 'Next'),
    '</p>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>',
    foot
  ), collapse = '\n')
}
```

Comment: That sounds very promising! And you would implement this by forking the repo and maintaining your own version of the package? Or is there a simpler way, e.g. by running `render_book` with a custom version of `build_chapter`?

Comment: Just running the new `build_chapter` will automatically overload the default one as in the `bookdown` code they're calling it directly